# C/C++ to Assembly language

Tags: assembly, c++, c, compilers, gcc

Is there any book or articles related to how C/C++ code is converted to assembly language, I mean common patterns for a specific compiler, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best thing to do would be to learn about compilation in general and code generation in particular. The [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) would be a good start. Then you can check Engineering a Compiler by Cooper & co.

About common compiler patterns, this would require a bit of extensive reverse engineering which, I believe, few people in the research and industrial community are ready to do/share. But, there's a guy named Agner Fog who does an extensive amount of benchmarking and analyzes the relationship of a compiler/code pattern with the underlying hardware architecture in terms of optimization. You can find his work [here](http://agner.org/optimize/).
What would be of interest to you is the **Optimizing software in C++: An optimization guide for Windows, Linux and Mac platforms**. It's simply a gold mine. Next, I would recommend : Optimizing subroutines in assembly language: An optimization guide for x86 platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a very good book (as in, it covers tons of patterns) at https://beginners.re/ - https://beginners.re/RE4B-EN.pdf

You can spend 5-10 years studying general theory of compilation, which will go forward during that time anyway, but if you need a reasonably quick compendium of current patterns for reference / quick training, use that book.